# Run setup creation using bat - install4j

Tags: install4j

I run the command:
"C:\Program Files\install4j6\bin\install4jc.exe" --license="xxx" 64DeveloperInstallation.install4j -r RADview_Test.exe

(in the xxx i put a valid license)
and i got the response: Updated licensing information.

My Goal is to run the setup creation using Bat file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute install4jc twice, once with

```
--license [license key]
```

and then with the other parameters for building your project.